# Is there a way to access an entire row with the GetRows() method?

Tags: asp-classic, multidimensional-array

I have used the GetRows() method to put a recordset into a 2D array.  I can access individual array items like this:

```
x = rows(colNumber, rowNumber)
```

Now I want to take a whole row / dimension from this array and pass it into another function.

Is there a method for doing this?  I haven't been able to find one. Looking for something like this:

```
entireSingleRow = rows(*, rowNumber)
```

Comment: No such thing in vbscript, to my knowledge, assuming this is all vbscript. Relatively easy to loop and create the 1-D set you're looking for.

Comment: Thought that might be the case... thanks for the pointer

Comment: @G.Stoynev better post this as answer with some code. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't such construct in the language, but the following "helper" will do"

```
REM 'Returns 1-D array of all "columns" in a "row" with index "rowNumber"'
REM 'from the 2-D "from2DArray" array (column, row)'
Function GetCols(ByRef from2DArray, ByVal rowNumber)
    Dim cols : cols = UBound(from2DArray, 1)
    Dim i
    Dim result()
    For i = 0 To cols
        Redim Preserve result(i)
        result(i) = from2DArray(i, rowNumber)
    Next

    GetCols = result
End Function

entireSingleRow = GetCols(rows, rowNumber)
```